# How to completely uninstall SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2012

I Uninstalled SQL Server Express 2012 from my PC. But after that, I noticed that there were other things at Programs and Features, like "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client", "Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client", "SQL Server Browser for SQL Server 2012" and another programs.

What can I uninstall from my PC to completely remove SQL Server 2012, without having problems with my Windows system?

Comment: Few things related to sql server gets installed when you install visual studio.order your software's by date installed and make sure you uninstall all software's installed at the time you installed sql server.

Comment: thanks for asking this question

Answer (score 5):

Honestly, Microsoft software is a pain to uninstall.

None of those things will uninstall eachother.

What I personally use for such an occasion is the IOBit uninstaller portable
http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/iobit_uninstaller_portable

It lets me remove all of them at once.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Moscato

Answer (score 1):

> Note the following important scenarios before you uninstall SQL
>   Server:
>
> 1. Before you remove SQL Server components from a computer that has the minimum required amount of physical memory, make sure that the
>      page file size is sufficient. The page file size must be equal to two
>      times the amount of physical memory. Insufficient virtual memory can
>      cause an incomplete removal of SQL Server.
> 2. If you have multiple instances of SQL Server, the SQL Server Browser uninstalls automatically when the last instance of SQL Server
>      2016 is uninstalled.
>
> If you want to uninstall all components of SQL Server 2016, you must
>   uninstall the SQL Server Browser component manually from Programs and
>   Features in Control Panel.

Also note that,

> Before You Uninstall:
>
> 1. Delete the local security groups. Before you uninstall SQL Server, delete the local security groups for SQL Server components.
> 2. Stop all SQL Server services. We recommend that you stop all SQL Server services before you uninstall SQL Server components. Active
>      connections can prevent successful uninstallation.
> 3. Use an account that has the appropriate permissions. Log on to the server by using the SQL Server service account or by using an account
>      that has equivalent permissions. For example, you can log on to the
>      server by using an account that is a member of the local
>      Administrators group.

Documentation: [MSDN - Uninstall an Existing Instance of SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms143412.aspx)